# Error while creating users in Oracle Identity Manager?

Tags: java, oim

While creating users, the error is popped up as:

```
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find resource for bundlejava.util.PropertyResourceBundle, key an error occurred while doing findEntity operation on User entity with id1
```

Also while searching the users, same error is pooped up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this issue you have to Export the UDF in your metadata file(User.xml). Delete all UDF's which are created and again Import the XML file.
For more details please refer following link.

[Click here](http://idmrockstars.blogspot.in/2015/04/exporting-and-importing-metadata-files.html)